# How do you use Ragged Tensors with tf.data and TFRecords?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Tensorflow recently released Ragged Tensors: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors

But there isn't any documentation on how to save ragged data as a TFRecord, and restore it using the data api.

Answer (score 2):

A ragged tensor needs two arrays: `values` and `something` defining how the `values` should be split into rows (e.g. `row_splits`, `row_lengths`, ... see the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/ragged_tensors#alternative_row-partitioning_schemes)). My take is to store these **two arrays as two features in a tf.Example** and create the ragged tensor when loading the files.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def serialize_example(vals, lens):
  vals = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=vals))
  lens = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=lens))
  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(
      feature={'vals': vals, 'lens': lens})
  )
  return example.SerializeToString()

def parse_example(raw_example):
  example = tf.io.parse_single_example(raw_example, {
      'vals':tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
      'lens':tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64)
  })
  return tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(
      example['vals'].values, row_lengths=example['lens'].values
  )

ex1 = serialize_example([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [3,2,5])
print(parse_example(ex1))  # <tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]>
ex2 = serialize_example([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [2,2,4])
print(parse_example(ex2))  # <tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]>
```

When creating a dataset from TFRecord files, one would apply the `parse_example` as a transformation by passing it to the `Dataset.map()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no **RaggedFeature** or equivalent. Your best bet is probably to convert to sparse (via `to_sparse()`) and encode your data as **SparseFeature**. After decoding, you can convert back to ragged via the `from_sparse()` builder.

Comment: EDIT: This is now supported: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27653

Comment: The referenced issue shows that this still has bugs, also it does not seem to show how ragged tensors can be written to `tfrecords`, just how you can use it in the `tf.data` api. Or did I perhaps miss something?